# What did i mess up in this for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

So what i'm trying to achieve here is basically doing a subnet *lookup* (in networking).

```
for (i = 0; i < sorEgy.Length; i++)
{
    if (sorEgy[i] == 1 && sorKetto[i] == 1)
    {
        Console.Write("1");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("0");
    }
}
```

sorEgy is the given IP in binary: 11000000101010000000000000100000 is for the given IP of 192.168.0.32.

sorKetto is the binary mask:11111111111111111111111100000000 is for /24 which means 24 1-s.

With this for loop, i wanted to write 1 in the output if both strings have a *1* at *i*, and write a 0 if they don't match. I can't really think of what the problem could be.

Comment: What are the data types of `sorEgy` and `sorKetto`? Are they strings?

Comment: What is your expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: Yes, they are strings, yeah.. forgot to mention that, and also i have an output, which is full of 0-s

Comment: My expected output would be 11000000101010000000000000000000

Comment: What do you see instead of your expected output?

Comment: converted to decimal `11111111111111111111111100000000` is your mask (255 255 255 0), not "24 1's".  And you should be comparing the same data types... is `sorEgy` and `sorKetto` a string or char array? If not, you may have to convert it for comparison.

Comment: you compare to `1`, but you should compare to `'1'` instead.

Comment: both are strings

Comment: If it's a string then the comparison needs to be `sorEgy[i] == '1'`, and then you do get the intended output: `11000000101010000000000000000000`

Comment: yeah silly me, never did this type of comparison before, but now i understand what i messed up, it works fine when i compare to the character '1', thanks!

Comment: Note that binary and with `char` of `'0'` and `'1'` works correctly, so you could just do `Console.Write((char)(sorEgy[i] & sorKetto[i]));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values being indexed are strings of the form `"100101010101111"`...  The index operator on the string produces a `char`, and a `char` may be compared to an `int`, which you are doing. But the `int` is the *Unicode 16 bit encoding* of that character, not the *text* of that character.

Unicode encoding 1 is an unprintable formatting code for "start of heading", not the character `1`.  If you want to compare to the *character* `1` then use `'1'`, not `1`, or use the Unicode encoding of the character `1`, which is `49`.  The preferred way to do it would be `'1'`, as comparing against `49` looks strange, to say the least.